# T chart : overloading series and chart method

Tags: .net, wpf, teechart

I'd like to add method to series and Chart class in api

Overloading Add method like this
int Add (Datetime x, double y, double index)
I want to add index parameter
Because of system need.
If I add this function to class.
I will be ok?
There are Any problems or issues?

Then I will add event function to Chart class.

In conclusion I need specific parameter Index and I have to recieve the parameter
When mousedown.

If someone have a experience like this work.

Please give me a advice.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which TeeChart version are you interested in: VCL/FMX, .NET, ActiveX, Java, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the *RectangleBubble* custom series example I made [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?p=26281#26281). This custom series adds additional [ValueLists](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/net/lib/html/SteemaTeeChartStylesValueList.htm) to the base class. You could easily retrieve any value from a *ValueList* in the *MouseDown* event, for example:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  InitializeChart();
}

private void InitializeChart()
{
  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
  tChart1.Series.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar()).FillSampleValues();

  tChart1.MouseDown += TChart1_MouseDown;
}

private void TChart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  int index = tChart1.Series[0].Clicked(e.X, e.Y);

  if (index != -1)
  {
    double value = tChart1.Series[0].YValues[index];
    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
  }
}
```

BTW, you may also be interested in custom series serialization discussed [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=7019&p=27464&hilit=rectanglebubble&sid=dc39550097232c8a971b8000b6dc5598#p27464).